# How to create URI's with a random string when creating something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

For instance, I have a Users resource. I am on 'users/new' and when I hit 'create my account' button, I want users to be redirected to 'users/somerandomstring' rather than users/id.

I do know how to create random strings and to redirect the concerned user to users/:id, but how do I use the random string as a part of the URI. What changes do I have to make to the routes and the database?

Can anyone give me brief idea of the Rails way of implementing this?

PS: I am not interested in using any gem even if one exists to this purpose. I would like to create one myself to learn my way around Rails ;)

Comment: Just store that string in a DB column and look it up in an action.

Comment: @SLaks So I don't have to make any changes to config/routes.rb?

Comment: Not necessary, just pass the random string instead of the user when building the url path.  So instead of `user_path(some_user)` you would use `user_path(some_user.random_string)`.  On the other side of the request, perform the lookup by random_string: `User.find_by_random_string(params[:id])`

Comment: @PinnyM @SLaks; Thanks again. That was easier than I thought.

Comment: Something like [Pretty/Friendly URL's](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) is what you are looking for...